# How can I create a new dataframe by subtracting the first column from every other column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns, difference

```
import pandas as pd
df = {'a': [1,1,1], 'b': [3,3,3,], 'c': [5,5,5,], 'd': [7,7,7], 'e': [9,9,9]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
dg = {'b': [2,2,2], 'c': [4,4,4], 'd': [6,6,6], 'e': [8,8,8]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dg, columns = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

```
df1
```

```
    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   3   5   7   9
1   1   3   5   7   9
2   1   3   5   7   9
```

df1 is my original dataframe. I want to create another dataframe by substracting column a from every other column (taking the difference between column a and all other columns).

```
df2
```

```
    b   c   d   e
0   2   4   6   8
1   2   4   6   8
2   2   4   6   8
```

df2 is the outcome.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Just `output = df1.drop('a',1).sub(df['a'],axis=0)` would also do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df1.loc[:,'b':].apply(lambda x: x-df1['a'])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   b  c  d  e
0  2  4  6  8
1  2  4  6  8
2  2  4  6  8
```

Comment: `.sub`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61971134/2780179)  is more efficient than `.apply`.

Answer (score 2):

```
df1.iloc[:,1:].sub(df1.a,axis=0)

    b   c   d   e
0   2   4   6   8
1   2   4   6   8
2   2   4   6   8
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to this would be

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'a': [1,1,1], 'b': [3,3,3,], 'c': [5,5,5,], 'd': [7,7,7], 'e': [9,9,9]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df1.columns[1:]:
    df2[col] = df1[col] - df1[df1.columns[0]]
```